# Why is my viewport performance (a lot) slower when using solid mode compared to rendered (eevee or cycles)?

Tags: 3d-view, performance

When I use solid mode for my viewport Blender suddenly becomes very slow and laggy. I can still move the camera around or change stuff, but only with a lot of delay. When I switch rendered mode the lag disappears. This is the case for Eevee and Cycles, the former being quicker of course.
The lag also disappears if I use wireframe mode or solid mode + X-ray.

I am using a particle system with 5463 objects, so there are a lot of objects in the scene. But why is the solid mode slower than the rendered mode?

[image: details of my blender scene]

My hardware:
AMD Ryzen 7 3800X
32 GB RAM
GeForce RTX 2060 Super

Can anyone help me? Should I provide any further information?

Thank you!

Comment: If the said particle system is hair, you might have not set the same amount of rendered particles. Sorry, can't comment yet

Comment: I am the one who asked the question, but unfortunately I can not login with my old account. @lastgoodname: Thank you for your answer but the particle system is Emitter, not hair.